# Accesing to Controls of Nested Form Array

Tags: angular, nested-forms, reactive, formarray

I want to reference Controls pointed in yellow colour in below image ,can any one help me how can i get hold of that reference so that I can push real time data.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: im able to get refrence until above formarray using following code, (<formarray>this.contracttemplateform.get('contractproperties')).controls , but im unable to get reference to next control

Comment: const test = (<FormArray>(<FormGroup>(<FormArray>this.contracttemplateform.get('contractproperties')).controls[0]).controls['templateTCText']);

Comment: im getting error like can't read property controls of null , when we are printing controls[0]

Answer (score 0):

you can get hold of that value by something this

`this.formArray.get('templateTCText').get('0')`

where formArray is the variable you are displaying in the question

Comment: The Json Structure which i needed is as follows
--------------
contracttemplateproperties
[
{
name:'cat',
title:'pet type',
templatetctext
[
{
'requiresspecialbid':'true',
'largetext':'descsription about cat'
},
{
'requiresspecialbid':'false',
'largetext':'descsription about dog
}
]
}
]
---------------------------
//fb form builder 
contracttemplateform=thi.fb.group
({
contracttemplateproperties=this.fb.array([])
})
--------------------------
how to form json structure ????

Comment: this.formArray.get('templateTCText').get('0') this doesnt work as it is present under another formarray